# Create A Subdomain Per User

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cloudflare, namecheap

I want to create a subdomain per user, eg: "bumpy.example.com". How do I do this? I'm using express, Heroku, Cloudflare, and Namecheap (domain provider, but Cloudflare is my nameserver). If you could provide steps that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few steps:

1. You need a custom domain name (ie: example.com).
2. Then you need a wildcard SSL for that domain name: (ie: `*.example.com`).
3. Then you need to setup your routing system to make use of that domain name, sadly not familiar with express, so this is as much as I can help you, but the gist is that you store the subdomain value for each user.

Also searching online for things like `Express <name of the database you use> Multi-tenancy` might help in terms of finding libraries to handle the backend logic.